# The result from the last row in mysqli php

Tags: php, mysqli, row

I want to get the result from the current and the last row from mysqli so I can see how the values changed. I need this for a statistical counter for my website

- row 1 = 400
- row 2 = 500
- row 3 = 650

This is my code so far:

```
while ($row = $Result->fetch_object())
{
    echo '
        <tr>
            <td>'.add_date_create($row->stat_AddTime).', '.add_time_create($row->stat_AddTime).'</td>

            <td>'.$row->stat_hacks_view.' +('.$row->stat_hacks_view-$row_stat_hacks_view--.')</td>

            <td>'.$row->stat_hacks_count.'</td>

            <td>'.$row->stat_game_view.'</td>

            <td>'.$row->stat_dev_count.'</td>
        </tr>
        ';
}
```

[...]

The result should be something like this:

- blabla row 1 400 +(400)
- blabla row 2 500 +(100)
- blabla row 3 650 +(150)

I hope I could explain what I mean.

I want to get that with `fetch_object()` if possible

Thanks!

Comment: use e.g. a `$temp` variable to save your last count. while looping through your results you can then dynamically calculate the difference between the last entry (`$temp`) and the current entry!

Comment: I tried that, but how can I make sure that it won't be override from the current results while looping?

Comment: i'll post my solution as answer, so i could better format it

Comment: Maybe you can count rows and then use @SaschaP response. Go trough loop as many times as you have rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use e.g. a `$temp` variable

```
$temp = 0;
while ($row = $Result->fetch_object())
{
    $current_value = $row->XYZ; // XYZ is your current value
    $difference = $current_value - $temp;
    $temp = $current_value;

    echo '
        <tr>
            <td>'.add_date_create($row->stat_AddTime).', '.add_time_create($row->stat_AddTime).'</td>

            <td>'.$row->stat_hacks_view.' +('.$row->stat_hacks_view-$row_stat_hacks_view--.')</td>

            <td>'.$row->stat_hacks_count.'</td>

            <td>'.$row->stat_game_view.'</td>

            <td>'.$row->stat_dev_count.'</td>
        </tr>
        ';
}
```

i don't know where to echo `$difference` in your code then, but maybe in the last `<td>`...

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but I have ~ 400 rows and the `$temp` won't update so it's always 0 and `$difference` will always be = `$current`

Comment: i'm sorry, actually updating my answer, found the error as well!

Comment: No problem, got it, too. Had to set the `$temp` after using it to the current value, will post the solution EDIT: Can't answer my own question :(

Answer (score -1):

query with `ORDER BY idcolname DESC LIMIT 2`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to limit the results, I want to echo result_n2 - result_n1, result_n3 - result_n2, and so on :/